# Offer IP to other end systems while behind router

Tags: nat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make my home PC a web server?](https://superuser.com/questions/21931/how-can-i-make-my-home-pc-a-web-server)

I am hosting a HTTP server on an end system that is behind a router. I want to offer my IP address so other people can access this HTTP server. Because of NAT however, I cannot just give my local ip address. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: I am sorry to see my question getting downvoted. I don't really know where else to go with it and it's hard to find an answer with google when you don't really know the terms to google for :-)

Comment: There's no down vote (right) now.  But it wouldn't surprise me, as we expect some research effort.  Go look at the question (and answers) I marked as a duplicate for some direction.

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/121435/is-it-possible-to-host-a-web-server-from-behind-a-nat?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/163507/problems-exposing-a-web-site-from-behind-a-router?rq=1 and a few others.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate of that. Thanks for the help and my apologies for the duplicate. It can be deleted if that is the policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Establish a forwarded port through your NAT. check http://portforward.com/ for instructions on your model of router. then clients can point to your routers public IP address, and traffic to the forwarded port will be sent to the specified port (probably 80) on your internal server.

Comment: If you're serving sensitive data through HTTPS then it will also need port 443 forwarded to your local box.